# Linux, quiero instalar en dualboot con Windows 7 y me aparece la pantalla en negro

Tags: linux

Qué tal, quiero instalar Peppermint OS junto a Windows 7, y cuando selecciono para instalar se queda en negro y se reinicia la PC. ¿Por qué podría ser? Gracias.

Comment: Saludos. Con el Linux que mencionas desconozco, pero cuando lo hacia con windows 7 (creo recordar hasta windows Me), lo primero era instalar el Windows (dejando el espacio suficiente o teniendo otro disco) para instalar Linux. Es decir primero es instalar Windows, luego Linux.

Comment: ¿El reinicio es inmediatamente después de iniciar el arranque desde el medio de instalacion por la BIOS? ¿O carga el bootloader (GRUB, o el que use esta distro)  correctamente pero se reinicia al  seleccionar una opción como "Peppermint Live"? ¿O el reinicio es  al ejecutar el instalador ya desde el escritorio del sistema operativo funcionando en modo "live"?